# SQL Server table creation date query

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2005

How can I get the table creation date of a MS SQL table using a SQL query?
I could not see any table physically but I can query that particular table.

Answer (score 173, accepted):

For 2005 up, you can use

```
SELECT
        [name]
       ,create_date
       ,modify_date
FROM
        sys.tables
```

I think for 2000, you need to have enabled auditing.

Answer (score 36):

For SQL Server 2005 upwards:

```
SELECT [name] AS [TableName], [create_date] AS [CreatedDate] FROM sys.tables
```

For SQL Server 2000 upwards:

```
SELECT so.[name] AS [TableName], so.[crdate] AS [CreatedDate]
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES AS it, sysobjects AS so 
WHERE it.[TABLE_NAME] = so.[name]
```

Answer (score 17):

```
SELECT create_date
FROM sys.tables
WHERE name='YourTableName'
```

Answer (score 10):

In case you also want Schema:

```
SELECT CONCAT(ic.TABLE_SCHEMA, '.', st.name) as TableName
   ,st.create_date
   ,st.modify_date

FROM sys.tables st

JOIN INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS ic ON ic.TABLE_NAME = st.name

GROUP BY ic.TABLE_SCHEMA, st.name, st.create_date, st.modify_date

ORDER BY st.create_date
```

Comment: Can I add a suggestion? I think the JOIN should be also on ic.TABLE_SCHEMA = schema_name(st.schema_id) otherwise, if you have tables with the same name but different schema, you will get duplication!

Answer (score 5):

For SQL Server 2000:

```
SELECT   su.name,so.name,so.crdate,* 
FROM     sysobjects so JOIN sysusers su
ON       so.uid = su.uid
WHERE    xtype='U'
ORDER BY so.name
```