# SQLite table creation date

Tags: sqlite, date, creation

Is there a way to query the creation date of a table in SQLite?
I am new to SQL, overall. I just found this [SQL Server table creation date query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1171019/sql-server-table-creation-date-query).
I am assuming that sqlite_master is the equivalent to sys.tables in SQLite. Is that correct?
But then my sqlite_master table only has the columns "type", "name", "tbl_name", "rootpage" and "sql".
If this is not possible in SQLite, what would be the best way to implement this functionality by myself?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SQLite does not store this data itself. Like you said, the `sqlite_master` table doesn't have any relevant column.

There's no particularly nice way that I can come up with to implement it. You could create some sort of interface for creating tables, and have it note the time whenever you create a new one, but anything created through a different method won't go through the same process. It also looks like there's no way to set a trigger on `CREATE TABLE`, so that's not an option either.

Why do you want this functionality? Creating tables seems like something you wouldn't be doing very often, maybe there's a better way to approach the problem?

Comment: I'm writing a mobile application for Android and I use the database as a cache for data I load from the internet. To reduce traffic I want to fetch the data from the database instead of reloading it if it is requested repeatedly but only if the table hasn't reached a certain age since the online data might change after some time. Using a custom interface for creating tables wouldn't be a problem since my database adapter class is the only part of the program directly accessing the database. What would be a good place to store the creation dates? Should I create my own custom master table?

Comment: Yeah, in that case I would just create your own table similar to the `sqlite_master` one. You probably only need two columns, table name and creation date.

Comment: In case someone else needs to do something like this too: I did something different now. I integrated a time stamp in the name of the tables themselves and built a framework around that and that works fine for me now. This way I don't have another table to look after.