# How to insert creation date of some tables into a new table?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have table like this:

[image]

I manually insert *generatedtime* by selecting the date on that table, but all I need right now that I need to get the generated time from this:

[image]

What may I do to get the creation date so that the creation date can be inputted into  a table? Thanks in advance

PS:  I know that the creation time of table can be shown in information_schema. But Is there any way to input the creation time into a new table? The example of the result is like this ibb.co/gO5xNa

Comment: What is your query? How can you compute the `creation date` value? Is it a constant (fixed)?

Comment: I still don't know what you want to achieve? Do you want to add the current time as creation time by default? Such that the DBMS insert the time at which the query is run automatically?

Comment: I want to add creation time of table from information_schema into a new table @flutter

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to get this information from the `CREATE_TIME` column in [`INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/tables-table.html)

Example:

```
SELECT TABLE_NAME, CREATE_TIME
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES
WHERE TABLE_SCHEMA = 'yourSchema'
;
```

Comment: yeah, I know that the creation time of table can be shown in information_schema. But Is there any way to input the creation time into a new table? The example of the result is like this https://ibb.co/gO5xNa

Comment: `CREATE TABLE newtable AS SELECT CREATE_TIME as 'generatedTime', TABLE_NAME as 'tempTable', true as 'NeedsToUpdateOrNot' 
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES
WHERE TABLE_SCHEMA = 'yourSchema'` ?  You'll have to set the update column

Comment: In case it's not obvious, you can of course do something like `WHERE 'table_name' LIKE 'temp%'` to get only the tables that are named tempXXX within your schema, or you can just move them to their own schema.

Comment: Thankyou for helping me to solve this problem. God Bless You ;) Have a nice day

Answer (score 0):

Get that information from 
Information_SChema.tables

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/tables-table.html

Comment: yeah, I know that the creation time of table can be shown in information_schema. But Is there any way to input the creation time into a new table? The example of the result is like this ibb.co/gO5xNa

Comment: @Neha

INSERT INTO table2 (column1, column2, column3, ...)
SELECT column1, column2, column3, ...
FROM table1
WHERE condition;

would do it?

Answer (score 0):

[This link shows you a halfway duplicate of your question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1171019/sql-server-table-creation-date-query)

Combine this with an update or insert, and you will be able to do what you want.

Comment: yeah, I know that the creation time of table can be shown in information_schema. But Is there any way to input the creation time into a new table? The example of the result is like this ibb.co/gO5xNa

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried look at CREATE_TIME field into INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES?

Comment: yeah, I know that the creation time of table can be shown in information_schema. But Is there any way to input the creation time into a new table? The example of the result is like this ibb.co/gO5xNa

Comment: This is not a answer to the question. This is a comment.

Comment: CREATE TABLE tablename as SELECT CREATE_TIME FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES WHERE table_schema = 'yourdb';
OR in existing table you can do like this
INSERT INTO tablename (field) SELECT CREATE_TIME FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES WHERE table_schema = yourdb'';