# How to create a modify table script for all tables

Tags: sql, sql-server, version-control

I'm always facing a problem that when I modify tables on a dev database I forget to  make the same changes on production machines. It's also hard (and tedious) to remember all the changes I made if i make a lot of them.

Is there some sort of solution to update production database/tables programmatically, or similar to getting latest version of files from version control?

Comment: There is something called replication that ensures that two databases are synchronized.

Comment: This should help you in the short term - it will show when tables have been modified: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1171019/sql-server-table-creation-date-query      You can save your DEV scripts and clean them up so they can be run hassle-free to modify tables in TEST, QA, PROD.

Comment: Before using source code control (wich I think is possible), there is an option in SSMS to "remind" you… in the Designer options, check "automatically generate change scripts".

Answer (score 1):

What I do is I simply just compare the Dev database and production database(or a backup copy of Dev database which I took before making any changes).

There are a lot of tools available to compare schema and data of 2 databases. One such tool is [redgate's SQL compare](https://www.red-gate.com/products/sql-development/sql-compare/)